# rails 5 has many pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5 I have a my models set up like this:

```
User
has_many :events, :through => :participants
Event
    has_many :participants
    has_many :users, :through => :participants
Participant
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :event
```

When I create an event I sent user_ids and a new participant is made.

However, now when I want to make a new event, a particular user may not be created yet.

What is a good pattern to check if a user does not exist, and then create said user before adding their user id to the event?

`user = User.find_or_create_by(email: email)
event.users << user`

Where should that happen?

Comment: One suggestion, use `through: :participants` instead of  `:through => :participants`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a good pattern to check if a user does not exist

There're `find_or_initialize_by` and `find_or_create_by` methods for this.

If users are subscribed by their emails:

```
event.users.find_or_create_by(email: email)
```

This will find or create a user and then subscribe to an event.

Comment: Where would be the correct place for this to happen? Which model callback?

Comment: That depends on the logic of your application. You can always perform it in the controller, since in controllers there're `params` according to which can be decided if a user exists or not. If the logic become too complex for the controller action, I'd suggest moving it into a service object. But I'd avoid putting the logic into model callbacks

Comment: By the way, I updated my answer. I recalled, that `find_or_create_by` can be called directly on the association.

Answer (score 0):

What about custom validation:

```
event.rb
validate :has_users

def has_users
  errors.add(:base, 'add at least one user') if self.users.blank?
end
```